# Swing GUI performing slow on UNIX

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I'm dealing with a strange problem.
I have a GUI built using swing. Its performance is very good at Windows but on linux/unix box its performance degrades to 10 times.

I'm using UIManager for GUI but I tried using LaF like

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

OR  `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());`

but didn't find any success.

Comment: We're going to need much more information, such as the specifics of the OSes and hardware, and what exactly your Swing app is doing (especially anything computationally or IO intensive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swing uses Java2D API to draw all of it's components which calls low level operating system functions for drawing. Is it possible that you haven't installed graphic drivers on linux right? I'm just guessing. Anyway provide more information about operationg system where did you try your application. Which windows manager did you tried at linux? Did you try your application on different computers? etc.

Comment: That sounds quite likely...  It would be good to know if Ritz has tried using any other non-native apps on his OS which use more sophisticated graphics.  Firefox would probably be a good start.

Comment: Driver was not installed properly.